# How does SHLoadIndirectString() work internally?

Tags: winapi, wine, react-os

I have been trying to get display names (user friendly name of an application) of all UWP applications installed on a system from a desktop application. I am trying to use `SHLoadIndirectString()` on the resource string obtained from the registry entry corresponding to those apps. Let us take the case of windows calculator.

**SHLoadIndirectString() Usage**

It's resource string can be obtained from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\‌​Repository\Packages\‌​Microsoft.WindowsCal‌​culator_10.1705.1301‌​.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbw‌​e\DisplayName` registry entry.
The resource string on my system for it is `@{Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1705.1301.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsCalculator/Resources/AppStoreName}`

To get the display name I would do `SHLoadIndirectString(@{Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1705.1301.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.WindowsCalculator/Resources/AppStoreName})`.

**Experimental observation**

1. ***(Experiment 1)*** I used `SHLoadIndirectString()` for two different users (U1, and U2). U1's language was set to english, U2's language was set to french (FR-fr). When SHLoadIndirectString() was run from U1 it returned `Windows Calculator`, and for U2 I got `Calculatrice Windows`. Thus the value returned for the same resource string depends on language setting of current user.
2. ***(Experiment 2)*** I installed a UWP app in U2, and did SHLoadIndirectString() to the resource string in DiplayName. I got error in U1, but in U2, it gave me the required string correctly.
3. ***(Experiment 3)*** When I added path to resource file `(resources.pri)`, to resource string, I got no error in U1. The resource string earlier was `@{DJiT.edjing-DJmixerconsolestudio-PlayMixRecordShar_5.1.12.0_x64__3nf5xjt6s13jt?ms-resource://DJiT.edjing-DJmixerconsolestudio-PlayMixRecordShar/Resources/AppName}`, which I later modified to `@{C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\DJiT.edjing-DJmixerconsolestudio-PlayMixRecordShar_5.1.12.0_x64__3nf5xjt6s13jt\\resources.pri?ms-resource://DJiT.edjing-DJmixerconsolestudio-PlayMixRecordShar/Resources/AppName}` before passing to `SHLoadIndirectString()`.

**Finding solutions**

1. [SHLoadIndirectString()'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759919(v=vs.85).aspx) says that its returned value depends on `Shell environment or ResourceContext`, without giving much details for each.
2. Two projects which try to re create windows NT API to run windows applications are [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) and [wine](https://www.winehq.org/). I looked through their source code to find implementation of `SHLoadIndirectString()`, but all that the codes seems to do is to do a `LoadLibrary()` on the resource string, after removing the `@` symbol at the beginning. This doesn't make any sense, why would there be such a dll in a system, as the resource string for every app is different?

   - [SHLoadIndirectString() implementation in ReactOS](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/8312df9fe0442112b0f6300690458e54f74b8bfd/reactos/dll/win32/shlwapi/string.c#L2821)
   - [SHLoadIndirectString() implementation in wine](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/07cf14dc928a1a00baecbbc7ca5a6f3fe680238c/dlls/shlwapi/string.c#L2842)

Comment: this is very huge and complex api. in what more concrete question ?

Answer (score 5):

From Windows XP to Windows 7 `SHLoadIndirectString` only used `LoadLibrary` with the `@filename.dll,resource` syntax documented on MSDN. The `MUIVerb` entry for file type registrations is perhaps the most common usage seen in the wild.

In Windows 8 it was extended to support other sources, specifically .PRI files ([Package Resource Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx)) used by WinRT/Modern/Store apps.

To find out exactly how it works you can single-step it in a debugger but these implementation details are not something you should depend on, you should only use the documented API.

On Windows 8 it uses various functions in MrmCoreR.dll (`mrmcorer!Microsoft::Resources::Runtime::CResource*`) to extract the package name, then it builds a path with `KERNEL32!PackageIdFromFullName`+`KERNEL32!GetPackagePath`+`"\resources.pri"` and then it calls `Bcp47Langs!Windows::Internal::CLanguagesListFactory::GetUserLanguages` to get a list of preferred languages. It then builds a string from the path (it converts `\` to `%5`) so it can check if the resource string is cached under `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MrtCache`. If not it reads the string with the resource manager. The exact details of how a [ResourceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext) works (language, DPI scale etc.) and how it finds the true source from the .pri file is probably out of scope for this question and a much larger topic in itself.